# Avoid using multiple if statements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create an if statement to check a condition for each iteration

```
          for in range(100):
            B10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
            T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0] )

            if np.abs(B10-T10) <=30:
                T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
```

I want to create an if condition that will get new values of T10 until the condition above is met for every iteration. How can I do this?

Comment: `until the condition above is met` - `while` loop?

Comment: Can you include example dataframe with expected output?

Comment: @h4z3 something of sort, just not sure how to use it in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead of a for loop:

```py
B10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
while np.abs(B10-T10) <= 30:
    B10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
    T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
```

or you can avoid redeclaring variables using the following:

```py
while True:
    B10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
    T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
    if not (np.abs(B10-T10) <=30):
        break
```

In general, it is a good practice to use a `for` loop when you know the number of iterations of your loop or when you are using collections. However, when you don't know it, i.e., when it depends on a condition, you should use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the loop and the if statement by generating the random numbers your want.  In your code, T10 will be a random value between max(0, B10 - 30) and min(UB, B10 + 10), inclusive.

```
max_delta = 30
B10 = np.random.randint(0, UB)
T10 = np.random.randint(max(0, B10 - max_delta), min(UB, B10 + max_delta  + 1))
```

where UB = precip.shape[0].

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, this should do it:

```
df['B10'] = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[0], df.shape[0])
df['T10'] = df['B10'].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0, x+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
while True:
    B10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
    T10 = np.random.randint(0, precip.shape[0])
    if not (np.abs(B10-T10) <=30):
        break
```